# Push to talk mic over music

Tags: audio, microphone, mixer, mixed-signal

I have an amplified mic and I want to mix it with an mp3 player output. I tried something like this without a relay (just a button with 2 pairs of contacts), but I hear a pop when I press the button (I don't know if it is because of the power supply of the mic is on or just the mechanical action of the contacts).

The main ideea I want to reach is that when button / relay not pressed, the music shall sound at maximum level. When button is pressed, mic shall mix with sound (with the sound with a smaller volume). I am trying to find a better approach (or a way to get rid of the pop noise).

This is my schematic, how can I improve it? Is it correct? Is it a solid state relay an option for this ?

[image]

Comment: Of course it will pop, as first the relay contact disconnects input audio and few milliseconds later connects to attenuated audio and mic. The mic thing uses single supply so you might have DC bias on output, or even if the output is AC coupled, the relay contact will make contact and discharge whatever DC voltage was charged to AC coupling cap. But you better know what kind of output stages and DC biases the player and mic has. Measure and read datasheets and schematics. We can't know how the devices you use will work.

Comment: This sounds like you want the PTT to gradually (where you define the meaning of that) lower the volume from the music source (probably through a gradually changing control voltage) while similarly raising the volume from the microphone, with a simple mixer combining the two. This means two voltage-controlled gain amplifiers (VGA/VCA) where the PTT causes a kind of see-saw of gain between them. (Perhaps on the order of 1/4 to 1/2 second?) Is that what you feel is right? Or am I misunderstanding you? And if so, can we assume line-level audio inputs and outputs? Or not?

Comment: Also, you may want to look for [line level mixers with priority](https://www.avc-group.com/int/en/product/denon-dn-312x-12-channel-line-mixer-with-priority/). Just a thought.

Comment: @jonk, yes that is what I want, but It can be more brutal (not gradually). I also don't understant what do you mean by "line-level audio inputs and outputs". And also it's something I would like to make myself, rather than buying some sophisticated tool. Thanks!

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu If you are going to custom-make the unit then the idea of *line-level* may not be as important since you know your microphone details (we don't) and what the output of this device will be driving (we also don't know that.) You already know what abrupt changes do and you have said you don't want that, either. It also seems you want the background to diminish, not go away. So it cannot directly drive speakers and must occur before the power stages. Anyway, I said you'll need 2 VCAs followed by a mixer stage. The PTT controls the gain used by each VCA in some manner you decide.

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu My guess, since you don't want 'pops', is that you will want to quickly limit the music, followed shortly by increasing the microphone. The trick will be in getting the VCA controls to each VCA 'just right.' Only you will know when that is achieved. But since you are DIY this, you can tinker until you get just what you want for the VCAs from the PTT switch events. The mixer part after that is trivial. Basic summing amp configuration. So I wouldn't dwell on that part since it's already 'known.' Maybe someone else has a better idea, though. That's my thought.